# remove object from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have two elements:

```
NSMutableArray* mruItems;
NSArray* mruSearchItems;
```

I have a `UITableView` that holds the `mruSearchItems` basically, and once the user swipes and deletes a specific row, I need to find ALL matches of that string inside the `mruItems` and remove them from there.

I haven't used NSMutableArray enough and my code gives me errors for some reason:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    //add code here for when you hit delete
    NSInteger i;
    i=0;
    for (id element in self.mruItems) {
        if ([(NSString *)element isEqualToString:[self.mruSearchItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {

            [self.mruItems removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
        else
           {
            i++;
           }
    }
    [self.searchTableView reloadData];

}
```

}

Error:
I see now that some of the strings are not between quotation marks (the ones in UTF8 are though)

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x1a10e0> was mutated while being enumerated.(
    "\U05de\U05e7\U05dc\U05d3\U05ea",
    "\U05de\U05d7\U05e9\U05d1\U05d5\U05df",
    "\U05db\U05d5\U05e0\U05df",
    "\U05d1 ",
    "\U05d1 ",
    "\U05d1 ",
    "\U05d1 ",
    Jack,
    Beans,
    Cigarettes
)'
```

Comment: Too messy to put in a comment, editing it into the question

Comment: You are editing the collection while enumerating through it.  That is your problem

Comment: I believe the quotations marks have their part in the problem?

Comment: 1. I love the contents of your array
2. ASCII-compatible strings aren't presented between quotes in log output. Weird, I know.

Comment: @MorganHarris the world needs more arrays like that.

Comment: Thanks, that's great news! @Morgan Harris +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get an exception because you are mutating a container while iterating over its elements.

`removeObject:` does exactly what you're looking for: removing *all* objects that are equal to the argument.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle != UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
        return;

    NSString *searchString = [self.mruSearchItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.mruItems removeObject:searchString];
    [self.searchTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thousands of apologies to the former responder (AND first responder ;)) @Michael Dautermann. I loved Michael's solution and I learned something new from him. This answer though, is sharp and clean in my taste, Thanks!

Comment: I've removed my offending answer.  I had tried to keep using the "`isEqualToString:`" selector as I thought "`isEqual`" was not functionally the same as "`isEqualToString:`.  [I was wrong about that](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/334-isequal-vs-isequaltostring/). But I wasn't wrong about the index "`i`" in the original code becoming out of order in relation to the mutable array after items were removed.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot edit the collection while enumerating through it, instead, store the indexes away, and then remove them afterwards by looping through your array of indexes.